# How to ask turtles patch in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

So far I am stuck with This but the third line does not seem to work. Can someone explain how to ask the turtle for his patch?

```
let otherTurtle min-one-of other turtles [distance myself]
let otherTurtleHeading [heading] of otherTurtle
let otherTurtlePatch [patch] of otherTurtle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  What you want is

```
let otherTurtlePatch [patch-here] of otherTurtle
```

`patch-here` is a reporter that returns the patch that the turtle is sitting on and, in this case, the patch on which otherTurtle is sitting.